# Как сделать сокрытие ресурсов SDK?

Tags: android

В разрабатываемой sdk необходимо скрыть ресурсы. Добавил в модуль sdk public.xml

```
<resources>
    <public name="mylib_app_name" type="string"/>
</resources>
```

Это никак не влияет на доступ к ресурсам из модуля тестового приложения (в том же проекте), но помечает ресурс как приватный если мы подключим эту сборку через jitpac в другой проект. Это просто пометка для lint. Доступ все ровно можно получить и скопировать верстку, ресурсы итд.

Как мне закрыть ресурсы для пользователей SDK?

Comment: Чтобы SDK можно было пользоваться, вызывать методы, использовать ресурсы (в т.ч. разметку) их надо сделать доступными для исполнения, и конечно, для просмотра. Сам код можно обфусцировать, что снизит его читаемость, а вот с ресурсами ничего сделать нельзя. Разве что вообще из SDK удалить. Возможно, вы хотите решить не задачу именно сокрытия ресурсов, а какую-то другую?

Comment: Я пытаюсь решить задачу - сокрытия верстки, чтобы ее нельзя было украсть пользователю sdk.

Comment: Имхо, эту задачу вообще решать не надо - во первых это невозможно - чтобы она работала через SDK она должна быть доступна вызывающим клиентам, т.е. должна быть читаема, а, значит, её и скопировать можно. Даже если бы это было возможно - не очень сложно можно и просто по внешнему виду с нуля такую же разметку нарисовать. Возможно, если всю вёрстку программно делать, а потом код обфусцировать - то копирование будет затруднено. Но вот тратить на это время смысла особого нет.